# Wordpress multisite and multiligual

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, multisite, polylang

I currently have a Wordpress site that runs on the following url:

blog.mycompany.com

this site has 3 languages nl, fr & en => polylang plugin is used for this
which will correspond the following urls:

- blog.mycompany.com/language/nl
- blog.mycompany.com/language/fr
- blog.mycompany.com/language/en

Now this blog will now also be used in other countries but on the same domain.

But content between countries has to be seperated. So I created a network of sites using subdirectories.

Now I want the url to be as followed:

- blog.mycompany.com/be-nl
- blog.mycompany.com/be-fr
- blog.mycompany.com/be-en
- blog.mycompany.com/nl-nl
- blog.mycompany.com/es-es
- ...

Still using polylang our wpml but I have no clue how to accomplish this and I hoped for some great tips that can help me forwards to accomplishing this.

Comment: You say that you have WPML installed?

Comment: @Ionut I have Polylang installed, but I also tried it with wpml. My prefered way is using polylang since the exicting website with more then 600 posts is using that. But mergin over to wpml is no problem.

Comment: Have you read this: https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/?

Comment: @lonut sure I did, but polylang isn't really the problem. I tried rewriting the url in my htaccess file but then Wordpress doesn't recognise my subsite anymore.